# Google Glass gestureDetector and setBaseListener

Tags: java, android, google-glass, gestures, touchpad

I want to implement the gesturedetector to set baselistener for my Google Glass. Android studio gave me an error saying the symbol `touchpad` cannot be found. I have already imported the relevant libraries.

`setBaseListener` continues to give an error.

```
private GestureDetector createGestureDetector(Context context,  GestureDetector.OnGestureListener listener) {
    GestureDetector gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(context, listener);

    //Create a base listener for generic gestures
    gestureDetector.setBaseListener(new GestureDetector.BaseListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onGesture(Gesture gesture) {
            if (gesture == Gesture.TAP) {
                // do something on tap
                return true;
            } else if (gesture == Gesture.TWO_TAP) {
                // do something on two finger tap
                return true;
            } else if (gesture == Gesture.SWIPE_RIGHT) {
                // do something on right (forward) swipe
                return true;
            } else if (gesture == Gesture.SWIPE_LEFT) {
                // do something on left (backwards) swipe
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code formatting is a bit off, but it seems you are initializing "gestureDetector" as

```
GestureDetector.OnGestureListener listener) { GestureDetector gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(context, listener);
```

However, according to the Glass GDK docs at
https://developers.google.com/glass/develop/gdk/reference/com/google/android/glass/touchpad/GestureDetector

I see only a single constructor: public GestureDetector (Context context)

Depending on where you are constructing this, could you try

```
GestureDetector gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(context);
```

or

```
GestureDetector gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(this);
```

with the following imports:

```
import com.google.android.glass.touchpad.Gesture;
import com.google.android.glass.touchpad.GestureDetector;
```

Comment: my initial constructor was 

GestureDetector gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(context);

and android studio prompted that the constructor was deprecated. According to their prompt, it led to the docs at http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/GestureDetector.html

Comment: @Bonsai is that javadoc link you sent a generic Android javadoc or something specifically for Google Glass GDK?  I'm running Glass XE22 (Android API 19) and GestureDetector gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(this); works beautifully for me.

Comment: You're importing the GestureDetector from the wrong package

Comment: @CoderOfTheNight the javadoc was prompted by android studio. i guess its a generic one but it still does not work. Could you post your code snippet?

Comment: @SimonMarquis which package should it be?

Comment: @Bonsai I just updated my answer+excerpt to also include the relevant imports:

import com.google.android.glass.touchpad.Gesture;
import com.google.android.glass.touchpad.GestureDetector;

Comment: @CoderOfTheNight i think i solve the error already. there was another import from android.view.gesture that cannot be deleted if it was imported before glass.touchpad.gestureDetector. 

Have to force android studio to read the second import instead. Thanks!!!